R window functions to create an ranking column
I have a dataframe and I want to produce a ranking column as per below.
example_data <- tibble::tibble(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  date = as.Date(c("2024-01-01", "2024-01-02","2024-01-03",
                   "2024-01-05", "2024-01-06","2024-01-07",
                   "2024-01-08", "2024-01-09","2024-01-10"
                   )),
  country = c("England","Scotland","Wales",
              "England","England","Scotland",
              "Scotland","Scotland","England"),
  ranking = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6)
  )

I tried but failed with the below:
example_data <- example_data |>
  dplyr::mutate(ranking2 = dplyr::dense_rank(country))


I assume I need to use a window function but can't work out how to achieve the ranking column.
Can anyone suggest any code?

You are probably looking for dplyr::consecutive_id(country) . Try example_data |>   dplyr::mutate(ranking2 = dplyr::consecutive_id(country))
